# Как исправить строчку html, если я не знаю, в каком документе она находится?

Tags: html, поиск, перевод

У меня есть код, мне нужно внести изменения в код, а именно в placeholder написать не "search", а "поиск". Через редактор элемента я способен внести изменения, но они не сохранятся.

Мне нужно открыть какой-то html файл, найти конкретную строчку, чтобы внести изменения, но я не знаю, где находится она, в каком html файле лежит. С CSS всё понятно, там указывается путь, откуда он этот стиль берёт, а тут как действовать? Помогите, пожалуйста, может, есть какой-то плагин, который позволит увидеть, откуда ноги растут?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: В данном случае не существует никакого HTML файла, так как конкретный сайт на WordPress. В файлы Вам лезть не стоит, особенно с Вашим уровнем навыков. Ознакомьтесь с [переводы (локализация)](https://wp-kama.ru/handbook/codex/translations)